# Specify nth operand in SLIB format (gettext scheme-format) specifier

Tags: scheme, gettext

I am working on the zh_CN l10n for guix, and it uses `scheme-format` messages. I tried to look for a way like `"Only %2$d bytes free on '%1$s'."` in [c-format](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/c_002dformat.html) to specify the nth operand for the string formatter in [scheme-format](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/scheme_002dformat.html), but was somehow confused by the description in SLIB manual section [Format Specification](https://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/slib/Format-Specification.html).

So, is there a way to achieve some similar effect with slib's `(format fmt ..)` that I can use with GNU gettext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have read the document more carefully -- apparently there is a way to jump arguments:

> `~*` Argument Jumping (jumps 1 argument forward).
>
> - `~n*` jumps n arguments forward.
> - `~:*`
>     jumps 1 argument backward.
> - `~n:*`
>     jumps n arguments backward.
> - `~@*`
>     jumps to the 0th argument.
> - `~n@*`
>     jumps to the nth argument (beginning from 0)